# Preserving state between different pages

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider, flutter-navigation, flutter-state

I've 2 different pages:

```
page1 -> page2
```

I'm navigating from page 1 to 2, using a button and `Navigator.push`. In both pages I simply show the value of a property called `name`. In the first page I instantiate a ChangeNotifier model defined like this:

```
class User extends ChangeNotifier {
    final String? name;
    
    User(this.name);
    
    set name(String? name) {
        this.name = name;
        notifyListeners();
    }
}
```

Now, in the second page I want to change the property `name` of the model, expecting that when I `pop()` the backstack (e.g. pressing back arrow) and showing page1 it already shows the updated value. I'm passing the model via:

```
Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (BuildContext context) => ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
              value: user,
              child: Page2Widget(),
            ),
          ))
```

In page2 I've wrapped with Consumer:

```
return Consumer<User>(builder: (context, user, child) {
      return TextButton(
        onPressed: () {
          user.name = 'Child';
        },
        child: Text(user.name ?? ''),
      );
    });
```

When I click the `TextButton` in page2 I got a stackoverflow error (well, it's quite weird posting it here). What is the reason of this loop? How can i solve? Is this the right approach to maintain the state between different pages? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you include your main method?

Answer (score 0):

You get a stackoverflow error because of your setter function

```
set name(String name){
  this.name = name;
  notifyListeners();
}
```

This function gets called infinite times, because you call it again by using `this.name = name` and you get recursion. You can change your function to this one:

```
void setName(String name){
  this.name = name;
  notifyListeners();
}
```